# How do you get the return type of a function in jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I have two files `src/a.js` `src/b.js`.I want the type of `response` to be the return value of the `request` function.

If in Typescript I could have written this ⬇️。Is there a similar syntax in jsdoc?

> I don't want to use `@typedef` to define an additional type.

```js
// src/a.ts

export function request() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    name: "William",
  });
}


// src/b.ts

import { request } from "./a";

export function handleResponse(response: ReturnType<typeof request>) {}
```

`src/a.js`

```js
export function request() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    name: "William",
  });
}
```

`src/b.js`

```js
/**
 * @param {???} response
 * @returns {void}
 */
export function handleResponse(response) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a similar effect in JSDoc without using @typedef, you can use import() syntax in the JSDoc comment to reference types from another module.

In your example, if you want to use the return type of the request function from `src/a.js` for the response parameter in the handleResponse function in `src/b.js`, you can do the following

**src/a.js**

```
/**
 * @returns {Promise<{name: string}>}
 */
export function request() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    name: "William",
  });
}
```

**src/b.js**

```
import { request } from './a';

/**
 * @param {ReturnType<typeof import('./a').request>} response
 * @returns {void}
 */
export function handleResponse(response) {}
```

Using import() in JSDoc comments allows you to reference types from other modules.

The syntax `ReturnType<typeof import('./a').request>` essentially translates to "the return type of the request function in the ./a module".

Comment if any more help required.